# In which store is the selection of a multiselector stored (extjs)?

Tags: extjs, multi-select

The documentation offers very limited information on the multiselector, and it is currently not even showing the sample code. In my work project which I cannot show,  A multiselector is given a store from which to show items to the user, and then in the controller, they use the same store to get the selected items. I don't understand how this works. Any insight will be greatly appreciated.

My research on this issue before posting includes the sencha documentation, sencha forums, and stackoverflow forums. Again, I found very limited information on how to retrieve items from a multiselector.

Comment: means do you want to get selected record for multiselector ?

Comment: yes I want to get the records that were selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is two way you can get selected data from [`MultiSelector`](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.3/classic/Ext.view.MultiSelector.html)

- Using `multiSelector.getStore().getData().items`- this store only contain selected data from search popup. This store will fill on selection change of search grid.
- Using `multiselector.searchPopup.down('grid').getSelection()`

Both method will return you selected record from `multiselector`.

In this **[FIDDLE](https://fiddle.sencha.com/fiddle/2i43)**, I have created a demo using `multiselector`.

**CODE SNIPPET**

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'Fiddle',

    launch: function () {

        Ext.create({
            xtype: 'panel',
            bodyPadding: 10,
            title: 'MultiSelector',
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            tbar: [{
                text: 'Get Selected recrod',
                handler: function () {
                    var multiselector = this.up('panel').down('multiselector'),
                        data = multiselector.getStore().getData().items;

                    alert(`Total record selected number is ` + data.length);
                    //Get selected record by searchPopup
                    if (multiselector.searchPopup) {
                        console.log('Get selected record by searchPopup', multiselector.searchPopup.down('grid').getSelection().length);
                    }
                }
            }],
            items: [{
                xtype: 'multiselector',
                valueField: 'id',
                displayField: 'name',
                showDefaultSearch: true,
                plusButtonType: 'add',
                hideHeaders: true,
                colspan: 2,
                search: {
                    xtype: 'multiselector-search',
                    store: {
                        type: 'store',
                        fields: ['id', 'name'],
                        autoload: true,
                        data: [{
                            id: 1,
                            name: 'Option 1 -- I want to get this'
                        }, {
                            id: 2,
                            name: 'Option 2 -- I want to get this'
                        }, {
                            id: 3,
                            name: 'Option 3 -- I want to get this'
                        }, {
                            id: 4,
                            name: 'Option 4 -- I want to get this'
                        }, {
                            id: 5,
                            name: 'Option 5 -- I want to get this'
                        }, {
                            id: 6,
                            name: 'Option 6 -- I want to get this'
                        }, {
                            id: 7,
                            name: 'Option 7 -- I want to get this'
                        }]
                    }
                }
            }]
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I didn't realize there was a **search** config where you can assign the store of the "search items" to be selected. Thank you!!!